# How to merge a Git branch using a different identity?

Tags: node.js, git, github

We are using Git for a website project where the `develop` branch will be the source of the test server, and the `master` branch will serve as the source for the live, production site.  The reason being to keep the git-related steps (switching branches, pushing and pulling) to a minimum for the intended user population.  It should be possible for these (not extremely technical) users to run a script that will merge `develop` into `master`, after being alerted that this would be pushed to live. `master` cannot be modified by normal users, only one special user can do the merge.

This is where I'm not sure how to integrate this identity change into my code below:

https://gist.github.com/jfix/9fb7d9e2510d112e83ee49af0fb9e27f

I'm using the [simple-git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git) npm library.  But more generally, I'm not sure whether what I want to do is actually possible as I can't seem to find information about this anywhere.

My intention would be of course to use a Github personal token instead of a password.

Answer (score 1):

Git itself doesn't do anything about user or permission management. So, the short answer is, don't try to do anything sneaky. Rather, use Github's user accounts they way they were intended.

What I suggest is to give this special user their own Github account, with their own copy of the repo. Let's say the main repo is at `https://github.com/yourteam/repo`, and the special repo is at `https://github.com/special/repo`.

The script will pull changes from the team repo's *develop* branch, and merge this into it's own *master* branch and push to `https://github.com/special/repo`.

Then, it will push its changes to the team's *master* branch. This step can optionally be a forced push, since no one else is supposed to mess with master, anyway. (In case someone does, using a forced push here means they have to fix their local repo to match the team repo later on, rather than having the script fail until someone fixes the team repo.)

At the same time, your CI software will notice that *master* has changed at `https://github.com/special/repo`, and will publish as you normally would. This is the linchpin: the CI doesn't pay attention to the team repo, so although your team has permission to change it, those changes don't make it into production.

This special user will need commit access to the team repo, in addition to its own GitHub repo. The easiest way is probably to use an SSH key, and run the git push command from the script, rather than trying to use the GitHub API.

Comment: jpaugh - thanks for clarifying that my initial idea won't work; I will try to put in place your suggestion which is a bit more involved as it requires another repo as well as more plumbing. Using an SSH key may prove a challenge in this corporate environment, especially when you have to put this in place on non-dev workstations. :-(

Comment: Well, if you're already using something like Jenkins to build and/or publish your app, you could also set up the script there, and have the users use a web interface to kick off the script. Then, the SSH key would be configured in one place (on the server).

Comment: Keep in mind that my idea also requires each user to have git installed locally as well, which is probably more hassle than sharing a single SSH key between each of them.

Comment: OTOH, there might be a better solution for your environment. GitHub might offer something specific to your use case.